# Vuetify 3 set custom icon for pagination in v-data-table

Tags: javascript, vuetifyjs3

I disabled the standard mdi icons and use custom icons in my application:

```
import { IconAliases } from 'vuetify'

const aliases: IconAliases = {
    'chevron-right': chevronRight,
    'chevron-left': chevronLeft,
    'page-first': pageFirst,
    'page-last': pageLast,
}

export default createVuetify({
    ...
    icons: {
        aliases
    },
    ...
})
```

I'm trying to replace the standard icons in pagination, but it doesn't give any effect

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    first-icon="$page-first"
    last-icon="$page-last"
    prev-icon="$chevron-left"
    next-icon="$chevron-right"
/>
```

Any thoughts on why this isn't happening?